# Understanding how to use ConvLSTM for multistep ahead forecasting

Tags: time-series, lstm, cnn, convolution, forecasting

I have a problem where I have transaction data for many banking accounts. The task is to train a model on historical debit/expense transactions and then forecast expense transactions for the next *n* days.

The data for each account is aggregated daily - I have total expense values for each account per day. I have done some research and found that the ConvLSTM model ([proposed here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04214v1.pdf)) is powerful for these multistep ahead forecasts. A example of this model to forecast the next 7 days of power consumption of a household is shown at the bottom of [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/).

I am struggling to understand how the convolutional unit is used within the LSTM unit to make these forecasts. Specifically I am having trouble understanding the shape that my input should be in to feed it into TensorFlow's [ConvLSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/ConvLSTMCell) (I think I will need to use the Conv1DLSTMCell sub-class?) and also what format the output/predictions will be returned as.

Comment: You should have seen that this method is developed for _spatiotemporal_ data... What is your spatial information? I'm wondering if you should go for regular LSTM...

Comment: @ignatius That's what I thought, but in the tutorial I provided, he uses it just for regular time series data. I also asked this question yesterday https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42872/recommended-model-for-univariate-or-multivariate-multistep-ahead-time-series-for?noredirect=1#comment49890_42872 where another user recommended that i use ConvLSTM

Comment: Please be sure to update the question with your progress, I am very interested in this topic and would be curious to see your progress, for this questions and your linked one.

Comment: Can you write a table/plot of your data, to see if it is 2D?